# Flameshot not working with Flatpak on Wayland

Tags: linux, gnome, wayland, flatpak, screenshot

I'm trying to take screenshot using flameshot on my fedora 38 system but the issue is I'm unable to do so. I'm running a wayland instance and do not intend to switch to X11.
I'm running the flatpak version of the app and I don't prefer to use the rpm version.

### What all is not working?

In short nothing is working

- When I click the icon on tray and select the option to capture screenshot nothing happens. When I quit from the tray then it then shows that there has been an error while capturing the screenshot.
- The custom shortcut is also not working.

### What I've tried?

I have tried many tutorials but wasn't able to find something specific.

### What I want?

I want to be able to take screenshot using a shortcut preferably

Your help is appreciated.
Thanks.